# Which relative clause is correct?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

Which one is the right format?

1. Who is the man who is Jane talking to?
2. Who is the man who Jane is talking to?

Comment: Where have you found these sentences?

Comment: *Who is the man whom Jane is talking to? Who is the man to whom Jane is talking?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2, since in the first sentence you are actually asking a question when saying "who is Jane talking to".